# Sapui5 OPA5 testing: How can i get to fragment that opens in popup?

Tags: sapui5

[image]

In "Home" view I have a button that opens a popup containing a fragment.
The popup is a fragment that is added to the DOM element.

When i do a OPA5 test for the home page it goes well but when i'm trying to access the popup with the fragment it doesnt work. (for example clicking the button or getting the image).

**How can i implement a function that is refering to the popup?**

- Home.view.xml
- Chat.fragment.xml

here is the OPA5 **HomeJourney.js**:

```
sap.ui.require(
["sap/ui/test/opaQunit"],
function (opaTest) {
    "use strict";

    QUnit.module("Load");

    opaTest("View init!", function (Given, When, Then) {
        // Arrangements
        Given.iStartMyApp();

        //Actions
        When.onTheHomePage.iLookAtTheScreen();
        When.onTheHomePage.iPressOnBotButton();
        When.onTheHomePage.iPressInDialog();/// Needs to click in popup
        When.onTheHomePage.iSearchInDialog();/// Needs to **search** in popup
        // Assertions
        Then.onTheHomePage.iShouldSeeTheHelloDialog();
    });
```

**Home.js**

```
    iPressInDialog: function () {
                    // Press action hits the "more" trigger on a table
                    return this.waitFor({
                        id: "__button13",
                        viewName: "Home",
                        actions: new Press(),
                        errorMessage: "did not find the Button",
                            success : function (oTitle) {
                                Opa5.assert.ok(oTitle.getVisible(), "closeBTN Button Was Clicked");
                            }
                    });
                },
```

**Chat.fragment.xml**

```
<core:FragmentDefinition 
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" 
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" 
xmlns:wt="com.sap.it.cs.iphome.controller.fragments"
xmlns:commons="sap.suite.ui.commons"
xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns="sap.m"
>
<Dialog id="Dialog">
            <content>
                <l:HorizontalLayout
                allowWrapping="false"
                class="sapUiContentPadding">
                    <Panel height="auto" width="auto" backgroundDesign="Solid">
                        <FlexBox>
                            <List  items="{msgData>/msgData}" >
                                <CustomListItem >
                                        <wt:MessageStrip
                                        text="{msgData>Text}"
                                        type="{msgData>Type}"
                                        showIcon="true"
                                        showCloseButton="false"
                                        customIcon="{msgData>customIcon}"
                                        >
                                    </wt:MessageStrip>
                                </CustomListItem>
                            </List>
                            <HBox width="100%">
                                <SearchField width="auto" class="sapUiSmallMargin" id="searchField" search="onSearch" liveChange="onLiveChange" placeholder="How can I help you?">
                                    <layoutData>
                                        <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
                                    </layoutData>
                                </SearchField>
                                <Button id="speech" icon="sap-icon://microphone" press="onAskClick" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop">
                                </Button>
                            </HBox>
                        </FlexBox>
                    </Panel>
                </l:HorizontalLayout>
            </content>  
</Dialog>
```

Comment: What does your Chat.fragment.xml look like?

Comment: @Allen i'v added the chat.fragment.xml, take a look, I need to get to the "searchField" and enter values there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `searchOpenDialogs` of `waitFor` . See [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.test.Opa5).

```
iSetSearchField: function(sValue) {
    return this.waitFor({
        viewName: "Home",
        controlType: "sap.m.SearchField",
        searchOpenDialogs: true,
        check: function(aSearchField) {
            if(aSearchField.length > 0 ) return true;
            return false;
        },
        success: function(aSearchField) {
            var oSearchField = aSearchField[0];
            oSearchField.setValue(sValue);
        },
        errorMessage: "Cannot set value for search field"
    });
},


iClickDialogButton: function() {
    return this.waitFor({
        viewName: "Home",
        controlType: "sap.m.Button",
        searchOpenDialogs: true,
        check: function(aButton) {
            if(aButton.length > 0 ) return true;
            return false;
        },
        success: function(aButton) {
            var oButton = aButton[0];
            oButton.firePress();
        },
        errorMessage: "Cannot click dialog button"
    });
},
```

Your journey code:

```
When.onTheHomePage.iSetSearchField("YOUR VALUE");
When.onTheHomePage.iClickDialogButton();
```

Comment: once again, you've nailed it!! Works like a charm! :)